# Message box for the replaced values count

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a task called Find and Replace in the DataGridView - It's completed.But i want the replaced count in the message box.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this? Below is my Find and Replace code:

```
private void btnFindandReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f.cmbColumnCombo.DataSource = cmbList;
        f.ShowDialog();


                if (recNo > 0)
                    recNo = recNo - 30;
            LoadPage(MyFOrmat, true);

}
 public void LoadPage(string Format, bool isFindAndReplace = false)
    {
        int startRec;
        int endRec;

        if (currentPage == PageCount)
        {
            endRec = (int)maxRec;
        }
        else
        {
            endRec = (int)pageSize * currentPage;
        }

        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        if (recNo == 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        }

        int rowindex = 0;
        startRec = recNo;
        for (int RowCount = startRec; RowCount &lt;= endRec; RowCount++)
        {
            if (datfile[RowCount].ToString() != "" )
            {
                if (RowCount == 0)
                {
                    string[] column = datfile[RowCount].Split('þ');
                    for (int i = 0; i &lt; column.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (column[i].ToString() != "") //if (column[i].ToString() != "" && column[i].ToString() != "\u0014")
                        {
                            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvtxtcountry = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                            dgvtxtcountry.HeaderText = column[i].ToString();
                            dgvtxtcountry.Name = column[i].ToString();
                            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvtxtcountry);
                            cmbList.Add(column[i]);
                            // dataGridView1.Columns["Sent Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                            i += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (RowCount != 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    string[] column = datfile[RowCount].Split('þ');
                    int index = 0;
                    for (int i = 1; i &lt; column.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (column[i].ToString() != "\u0014")
                        {
                            //if (i == 3)
                            //{
                            //    dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(column[i]).ToString(Format);
                            //}
                            //else
                            //{ 
                                dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = column[i].Trim('þ'); 
                            //}

                            if (StaticVar.FnR == true && index == StaticVar.colindx)
                            {

                                if ((column[i]).Contains(StaticVar.Find) != null)
                                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = column[i].Replace(StaticVar.Find, StaticVar.Replace);
                            }
                            if (StaticVar.DateFormat != "" && StaticVar.DateFormat != null)
                            {
                                if (StaticVar.datecolidx == ((i - 1) / 2))
                                {
                                    dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(column[i]).ToString(StaticVar.DateFormat);
                                }
                            }

                            index += 1;
                            i += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    rowindex += 1;
                }
            }
            recNo += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a integer in your code which counts up everytime you do a replace and in the End put `MessageBox.Show("Count: " + count)`.
Additional information: you do nothing with `bool isFindAndReplace`, maybe you forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `replaced` variable and increment it every time you replace a value. Show a message box at the end of the method.

```
public void LoadPage(string Format, bool isFindAndReplace = false) {
    int replaced = 0;

    ....

    if ((column[i]).Contains(StaticVar.Find) != null) {                                          
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = column[i].Replace(StaticVar.Find, StaticVar.Replace);
        replaced++;
    }

    ....

    if(isFindAndReplace)
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} occurrence(s) replaced.", replaced));
}
```

Comment: Hi,
It's working good and very thankful to you for a brief description. But after aoolying this code, When i click on find and replace, It's replacing only 1 record and getting message box as 1 record got replaced and if i click OK, it's replacing second value and press OK, it's replacing 3rd value and so on.......

Comment: @Aditya You have to move `MessageBox.Show` to the end of the method (out of the loop `for (int RowCount = startRec; RowCount <= endRec; RowCount++)`). Look at my post once more - there is only the curly brace after the `MessageBox.Show`, nothing more.

Comment: if (StaticVar.FnR == true && index == StaticVar.colindx)
                                {

                                    if ((column[i]).Contains(StaticVar.Find) != null)
                                        dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = column[i].Replace(StaticVar.Find, StaticVar.Replace);
                                    replaced++;
                                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} No: of values replaced is: ", replaced));
                                }

Comment: @Aditya It's not what is in my post. Look at it once again. See the dots and the curly brace? The right place is: ` } rowindex += 1; } } recNo += 1; } MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} No: of values replaced is: ", replaced)); }`

Comment: Hey, I have overlooked it. It's my mistake and i's working now. Thanks a lot.
Now when i'm loading the page, i'm geting this message box No: of values replaced : 0.
Why it's coming onloading/

Comment: As the method is on Pageload, i'm getting that message box repeatedly. can you help me how to get that message box only when i use Find and replace.

Comment: @Aditya Maybe this would help: `if(isFindAndReplace) MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} No: of values replaced is: ", replaced));`. I've modified my answer.

Comment: @Aditya At the very end of the method's body. Just insert text `if(isFindAndReplace)` before `MessageBox`.

Comment: Now i'm not getting this pop up at the pageload. But after clicking on Find and Replace, i'm getting popup saying value 1 replaced.
After clicking OK, another record displayed and Value is replaced...... Same like previous as i mentioned, i'm getting multiple popups one after other.

Comment: @Aditya You have placed the code in the wrong place. Place it at the very end of function's body, outside of any loop.

Comment: If the replaced value count is 1 also, it's showing 30 everytime.

Comment: @Aditya Probably statement `replaced++;` is placed in the wrong place.

Comment: I pasted the code as you posted Romanoza. 
if (StaticVar.FnR == true && index == StaticVar.colindx) 
{ 
if ((column[i]).Contains(StaticVar.Find) != null) dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = column[i].Replace(StaticVar.Find, StaticVar.Replace); replaced++; 
}

Comment: Hi,
I have tried multiple ways to show the correct count in message box. But every time it's showing no: of replaced values is 30 even if the replaced value is 10

Comment: @Aditya Try to post another question with the complete source code, please. You have another bug in the code, maybe someone will help you to debug your code.